# Merge and extract product data from numerous SQL tables to Hadoop key-value store with Scala / Python

Tags: python, scala, hadoop

Need advice on the following task: Merge and extract product data from numerous SQL tables. Records in these tables contain product ID and different attributes of this product. Resulting data should be stored in a HDFS table, where any given record represents all attributes related to a given product. Resulting record may have variable number of attributes. For example:

```
Input SQL records:
    Table 1
        Rec 1: |ProdId|x11|x12|x13|...|x1N|
        Rec 2: |ProdId|x21|x22|x23|...|x2N|
        ....
        Rec M: |ProdId|xM1|xM2|xM3|...|xMN|

    Table 2
        Rec 1: |ProdId|y11|y12|y13|...|y1K|
        Rec 2: |ProdId|y21|y22|y23|...|y2K|
        ....
        Rec L: |ProdId|yL1|yL2|yL3|...|xLK|
    ....
    ....
    ....
    Table Z
        Rec 1: |ProdId|z11|z12|z13|...|z1Q|
        Rec 2: |ProdId|z21|z22|z23|...|z2Q|
        ....
        Rec P: |ProdId|zL1|zL2|zL3|...|zPQ|

Output HDFS Table:
        Rec 1: |ProdId|x11|x12|x13|...|x1N|y11|y12|y13|...|y1K|z11|z12|z13|...|z1Q|
        Rec 2: |ProdId|x21|x22|x23|...|x2N|y21|y22|y23|...|y2K|z21|z22|z23|...|z2Q|
        ....
        Rec R: |ProdId|xI1|xI2|xI3|...|xMN|yJ1|yJ2|yJ3|...|xLK|zF1|zF2|zF3|...|zFQ|
```

Resulting record should have named fields and stored in HDFS so it would be easy to be used in map / reduce jobs written in Scala / Java / Python.

I am new to Hadoop and may be wrong. Using Hive for this task looks somewhat awkward to me. Map-reduce would be nice to use, yet I don't see how to import input SQL data with scoop to table other then Hive with named fields. Is there any way to export SQL table to HBASE that will reconstruct fields names automatically? Any other key-value store good for this task that supports named fields? Ideally would be to find framework that would allow to do this job in Scala or Python.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, this task is usually performed by [scoop](https://sqoop.apache.org/) tool. It is intended to be [used from cmd](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.99.3/Sqoop5MinutesDemo.html), but extending it with Scala is perfectly possible, since it is written in java.

Comment: In my case I have about 50 SQL tables with different schemas. Without getting into details of these schemas I need to merge them based on a single field 'ProductID'. Not sure that sqoop can do this without SQL instructions. All I need - import these tables one by one with sqoop and then run MRD job with ProductID as a key. Question is how to import SQL with field names? I can import to Hive, but how then can I run MRD job on Hive tables?